# How to export a table with code into a file

Tags: export, firebird

I would like to export a table from Firebird database into a CSV file. With MySQL, I can use an SQL with additional commands like `INTO OUTFILE`. Here is an example:

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

This query can be submitted on several sql-query-tools (MySQL WB, HeidiSQL, ccenter).
Is it possible using, for example FlameRobin, to submit an SQL statement like above to export data from Firebird?
I may use FlameRobin using the menu or another tool like FBexport, but I prefer the one-code solution without clicking on the menu or using additional tools (FBexport).

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to perform an action like this in Firebird. The engine itself does not have any support to export data and each tool have (or don't have) it's own way to allow you to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird does not support that directly. You'll have to use some tool (either GUI or CLI) to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I know its a lil bit late... But 
There is a way to export it using OUTPUT ISQL command.

It will be like:

```
`OUTPUT C:\file_name.txt;`
`SELECT A, B, A+B FROM EXMAPLE_TABLE;`
`OUTPUT;`
```

So the content of your select statement will be on your txt file.

Remember to create the empty file before using the OUTPUT;