Convert .fdb to mysql
I need convert a .fdb file to MySQL (.sql) or CSV.
I don't have Windows, would be nice to have a Linux/MacOS SO.
Any idea to do it?

Install Firebird, proper version. Connect to the database and export the structures (to .SQL) and the data (to .CSV) using any client tool. Remove Firebird. Install MySQL. Fix structures in .SQL according to MySQL syntax in any text editor. Import structures. Import data.

Do u know some client for macos I can use? I tried isql but i'm getting this error "[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect"

The fdb tag is for the Flash Debugger. Is that really relevant to this? https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fdb/info

Removed fdb tag.

You need to run the Firebird Server to connect. isql is only a client. Once you have a Firebird Server running, there are already posts on Stack Overflow about exporting to CSV. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14454618/20860 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/69708042/20860

@VicenteEcho JFYI: Firebird isql and ODBC isql are different applications though they share the name.

Do u know some client for macos I can use? AFAIR standard gbak creates textual dump which can be used. Of course it needs in huge edition for to provide the compatibility with MySQL syntax.

@Akina Firebird's gbak produces a binary backup.

There are (paid) tools to do such conversion, not so sure about free tools to be honest. You could also do some work to create the corresponding database structure in MySQL, and write some code to pump the data from Firebird to MySQL using your favorite language.

You can export content of Firebird database into CSV files using FBExport.
Then you can import these data into MySQL using My SQL Workbench Data Import Wizard or LOAD DATA command.
